# Model Form subclassing and hiding elements

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Accordingly to the Django docs I can do the following:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                                help_text="Use puns liberally")
    content = models.TextField()


class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    headline = MyFormField(max_length=200, required=False,
                           help_text="Use puns liberally")

    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

In my case I would like "headline" not to be displayed at all as an option in a subclass. What is the best method to do that? I already tried "exclude"

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ["headline"]
```

But since it is declared in the parent it is rendered anyways. Also I tried declaring it as headline = "" but same result.

**Solution:**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NameOfSubclassedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    del self.fields['headline'] # field that needs removing
```

TIA

*update: in my original post I placed exclude outside meta by accident

*update2: bug already reported: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13971

*update3: Added Solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply have put your exclude in the wrong place.  Try it like this:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ("headline",)
```

Check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

Comment: @peter my apologies, i in fact placed exclude inside Meta, I placed it outside while generating the sample.

Comment: In that case, are you certain everything is spelled correctly?  And indented correctly?  That is precisely how the docs say to exclude a field from a `ModelForm`.

Comment: Actually, I just tested this myself, and exclude has no effect on a field defined on the form itself in a parent class. This might be a Django bug.

Comment: @jack: I am certain everything is spelled correctly and intended correctly but there is always room for error but so far everything seems to be in place. The second time I declared ArticleForm was just as part of my example.

Comment: @chrispratt: Glad to hear some one else was able to reproduce. For now I am trying to find a different way to hide the field. It works for me as well for items that are not defined within the form.

Comment: Ok, after doing more research I found out it is a bug and it is already submited https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13971

Comment: Interesting. The workaround posted on that ticket doesn't appear to work, in 1.2.5 at least. You get a TemplateSyntax error as it tries to render a key that no longer exists in the field dict.